# Eclipse's "Outline" window equivalent in IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-13

I am thinking to switch from Eclipse to IntelliJ. But I want first make sure that my favorite tools exists in IntelliJ.

> Does **IntelliJ** has an equivalent to Eclipse's docked **Outline** window?

[image: Eclipse outline window example]

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I think you're looking for [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html):

**To view the file structure, do one of the following**

- On the main menu, choose View | Tool Windows | Structure.
- Press StructureTool Button
- Press Alt + 7. [Cmd + 7 in Mac]
- Press Ctrl + F12.

Comment: It doesnt show the member variables, shows only methods, can someone help how can i see those member variables too

Comment: In my case, there is a button `Show Fields` for Python code, so you can turn it on and off. There is no such button for Scala, however fields are shown by default. So, it seems like it is plugin-dependent.

Comment: On a Mac it is ⌘ + 7  (Command+7) _not_ Option+7 as the linked help page says.

Comment: @anubhs There is a "Show fields" button on the toolbar of the tool window.

Comment: Update: And InteliJ finally allows to place that side-by-side next to file window like in Eclipse: Settings -> Appearance -> Tool Windows -> Side-by-side layout on the left. Then place it to the left-down corner.

Comment: I swear IntelliJ is so complicated and I don't find the advantages of it

Answer (score 11):

File structure popup shortcut:

- Windows: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

the equivalent of "outline" in eclipse is: "structure" on intellij,
to display structure :

1. View => Tool windows => Structure
2. or use the shortcut: Alt + 7

Comment: Same answer as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31752579/16019058)